# how to select data from two table where one table containing multiple columns with ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

- products: id, product_name, color_1(id), color_2(id), color_3(id)
- colors: id, color

I want to select all product with the colors.

#### Products:

```
id  product_name    color_1(id) color_2(id) color_3(id)
--------------------------------------------------------
1   Apple       1       2       3
2   Table       2       3       0
```

#### Colors:

```
id  color
---------
0   False
1   Blue
2   Green
3   Yellow
```

I want to get in one query:

```
1   Apple       Blue        Green       Yellow
2   Table       Green       Yellow      False
```

Comment: The query is quite simple, but you should try it yourself and post it here if unable to do it, so others can help you

Comment: One important fact that the answers below have omitted: You can reference the same table more than once by giving it an alias.  `JOIN colors AS c1` gives the name `c1` to on reference to `colors`.  This allows you to have *another* JOIN on to the same table again, with a difference reference name/alias; `JOIN colors AS c2`, etc, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Use inner joins.

```
SELECT     p.product_name, c1.color, c2.color, c3.color
FROM       Products p
INNER JOIN Colors c1 ON c1.id = p.color_1
INNER JOIN Colors c2 ON c2.id = p.color_2
INNER JOIN Colors c3 ON c3.id = p.color_3
```

**Based on your comments**:

If you want to get results in the case that some of the product color IDs do not apply then switch to LEFT OUTER JOIN. This will not filter out records, and simple returns NULL for all columns if there is no value to join on.

```
SELECT          p.product_name, c1.color, c2.color, c3.color
FROM            Products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Colors c1 ON c1.id = p.color_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Colors c2 ON c2.id = p.color_2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Colors c3 ON c3.id = p.color_3
```

Comment: @NoamVaza See my response for dealing with colors that do not exist in the colors table, yet you still want to get your result set. And please accept solution if you've found this helpful. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select p.id, p.product_name, c1.color, c2.color, c3.color
from products p, colors c1, colors c2, colors c3
where c1.id=p.color_1 and
      c2.id=p.color_2 and
      c3.id=p.color_3
```

Comment: Use joins, not a cartesian product.

Comment: @Jay - While I agree with you that JOINs are better best practice *(I hate `,` notation)*, that is a whole different discussion and has been covered many times in many SO questions.  For the notation used here, this is a correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, so for best performance what is the best? join or cartesian product?

Comment: join, although some query optimizers might translate the cartesian themselves.

Comment: Thanks, following this question, if color_X(id) don`t exists in Colors table, query returns empty string.

Comment: @NoamVaza Yes, the query will not return a result if there's no corresponding id in in the colors table.

Comment: how can I get a result if the product have only two color?product.color_3=0 product.color_4=0 
And color.id=0 is not defined (I don`t have the option to define it)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select p.id, p.product_name, c1.color color_1, c2.color color_2, c3.color color_3
from products p
join colors c1 on p.color_1 = c1.id
join colors c2 on p.color_2 = c2.id
join colors c3 on p.color_3 = c3.id
```

You just need to make a join on every field to get the appropriate color.